# TIFF file will save but is blank in conditional statement (if statement)

Tags: r, tiff

I am having an issue with a TIFF files saving, but the graph does not have any content in it. This is specifically happening with an if statement.

```
if (RMCAv_Graph == T){
Save_Path = file.path(Sub_Folder_Path, "RMCAv.tiff")
tiff(file = Save_Path, units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 600)
RMCAv_Plot
dev.off()
}
```

I tried to put it into the conditional statement and without the graph. When I put the if statement in the graph, it will not populate as expected.

Comment: is RMCAv_Graph is of type `boolean`?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are writing to file inside of a conditional statement, you need to directly tell it to print.

```
if (RMCAv_Graph == T){
   Save_Path = file.path(Sub_Folder_Path, "RMCAv.tiff")
   tiff(file = Save_Path, units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 600)
   RMCAv_Plot %>% print()
   dev.off()
}
```

or without the pipe:

```
if (RMCAv_Graph == T){
   Save_Path = file.path(Sub_Folder_Path, "RMCAv.tiff")
   tiff(file = Save_Path, units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 600)
   print(RMCAv_Plot)
   dev.off()
}
```